# Oredering second axis on graphic - MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot two axis with MatPlotLib, unfortunately secondone (EmplK and Vol_M) is not ordered correctly. I know that issues is fixing with zip() but my code still do not work. Could you please support me with fix of that issue and also to tell me what code to add to change 1,2,3,4.. with the names of the Sectors.

````
dataset = three[['Market_Cap_B','Ent_Value','Revenue','EBITDA']]
dataset2 = three[['Empl_K','Vol_M']]
 
ax = dataset.plot(kind = 'bar',figsize=(12, 8))
ax2 = dataset2.plot(kind = 'line',secondary_y = True, ax = ax, figsize=(12, 8))

#ax, ax2 = zip(*sorted(zip(ax, ax2)))
    
    
plt.title("S&P 500 by Sectors - July 2023") 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()```
````

[image]

I tried to fix with zip() - unsuccessfully

Comment: We don’t know what the “three” object is. Please provide a complete self contained example.  If it is a pandas data frame then pass ax as an optional argument to the plot method

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is three - three = final_df[['GICS Sector','Market_Cap_B','Ent_Value','Revenue','EBITDA','Total_Debt','Total_Cash','Empl_K','Vol_M','OCF','FCF',]].groupby(['GICS Sector']).sum().reset_index().round(1).sort_values(by=['Market_Cap_B'], ascending=False)
table with values from which I choose columns

Comment: What Jody is saying is that we don't have the data or DataFrame information to understand your code.

Comment: Try sorting the data, not the plot.